# Safely inserting data into SQLite database with apostrophe

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am trying to create a table in a SQLite database based on user provided text.  Everything was working correctly, except when I tried to add an apostrophe inside the text (which was to be the new table name).  After research, I determined that what I was doing is not the best practice as is vulnerable to injection:

```
    const char *sqlStr = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CREATE Table '%@' ('Name' 'char(50)','ID' 'integer')",theString]UTF8String];
```

So I am trying to find a way to allow apostrophes to be included in the table name and safely inserting the value into the database.  I have read about binding values, but is this possible with the 'CREATE TABLE' statement?  Or only when you insert data into an already existing table?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would not recommend allowing the user or some other dynamic way of naming columns. If anything name the column custom1.

Comment: Hi Joe, I want to let the user create the table name in the database, not the columns, those are not going to be changeable.  I just don't know the best way to do this when working with apostrophes.

Comment: If you use [FMDB](http://github.com/ccgus/FMDB), then it will handle all of the necessary escaping for you before executing your SQL (provided you use its API for substitution). I *highly* recommend that you check it out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html):

> A string constant is formed by enclosing the string in single quotes ('). A single quote within the string can be encoded by putting two single quotes in a row - as in Pascal.

Thus:

```
[theString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"''"];
```

Comment: I have used this to insert values, but when i tried to retrieve it from DB it gives me blank row. like `"Select * From TABLE WHERE Name = 'tom''s'"`

Comment: @User_1191```# Do this instead
t = ("tom's",)
c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol=?', t)```